# Disadvantage to having tasks wait in GAE push queues for hours/days?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there any disadvantage to adding tasks to a Google App Engine [task push queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/) that have a countdown timer worth hours or days? Could queue performance be adversely affected if I have hundreds of (small) tasks waiting in the queue like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you presented does not seem to incur in any of the current limits for Task Queues, so there should be no problem regarding the performance of your scheduled tasks.

You can find detailed information on the quota limits for Task Queues [in this page from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Task_Queue), but just to get you a general idea, below I summarize some of the key features you seem to be interested in (assuming you have billing enabled):

- Maximum stored tasks that have not yet been executed: **10,000,000,000**
- Maximum number of queues: **100**
- Daily Limit for Task Queue API calls: **1,000,000,000**
- Queue execution rate: **500 tasks per second per queue**
- Maximum countdown for a task: **30 days from the current date and time**

So given the indicative figures you provided, your Task Push Queues should be able to handle your requirements. Just bear in mind that the maximum countdown timer equals 30 days, which is the only limit you may hit in your application.

Comment: Thanks! As per current plan I shouldn't need to schedule anything more than 7 days out, so this is perfect!